# Graphviz svg output, groups not positioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Graphviz is giving me output that looks basically like this:

```
<svg>
  <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(0.138865 0.138865) rotate(0) translate(4 4648)">
    <title>G</title>
    ...
    <g id="node36" class="node">
      <title>SomeTitle</title>
      <g id="a_node36">
        <a>
          <ellipse cx="1225" cy="-3546" rx="85.1304" ry="18">
          </ellipse>
          <text x="1225" y="-3541.8">
          sometext</text>
        </a>
      </g>
    </g>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

I am no Svg expert, but it seems that since the contents of the nodes are positioned relative to the graph group and not the node group, doing a `scale` on a node is going to have undesired results. Do I have to walk the graph and "normalize" everything? Is there a switch on Graphviz to do this?

Does the normalization algorithm take the the upper left of the bounding box described by the `x` and `y` of the groups elements, and use that as a translate for the group and adjust the members to the new coordinate system?

I am using jQuery Svg, as well as D3 -- do either of those have a normalize function that would help in this situation?
This seems a pain, so I have to ask why is this the reality.

Comment: What sort of scale are you talking about?  Making a node larger at its current position?

Comment: Yes, doing a transform with a matrix or scale etc at #node36

Answer (score 1):

Since the origin of the document is, by default, at the top left, doing a straight scale of the node will also cause it to move.

However that would be true in all but the specific situation in which the node is centred on the origin.  Correcting that problem is fairly simple. SVG transforms can be built up from a series of basic transformation operations.

To scale an element around its centre point you have all you have to do is:

1. translate the centre point to the origin: `translate(-1225,3546)`
2. scale: `scale(4)`
3. translate it back to its original location: `translate(1225,-3546)`

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(0.138865 0.138865) rotate(0) translate(4 4648)">
    <title>G</title>
    
    <g id="node36" class="node">
      <title>SomeTitle</title>
      <g id="a_node36" transform="translate(1225,-3546) scale(4) translate(-1225,3546)">
        <a>
          <ellipse cx="1225" cy="-3546" rx="85.1304" ry="18" fill="blue">
          </ellipse>
          <text x="1225" y="-3541.8" fill="white">
          sometext</text>
        </a>
      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="node36" class="node">
      <title>SomeTitle</title>
      <g id="a_node36_orig">
        <a>
          <ellipse cx="1225" cy="-3546" rx="85.1304" ry="18" fill="red">
          </ellipse>
          <text x="1225" y="-3541.8" fill="white">
          sometext</text>
        </a>
      </g>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

Note that, due to the way transforms work, the operations are listed in reverse order in the `transform` attribute.